# Fetching data from MySQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have 3 tables namely:
1)attendance
2)registration
3)schedule

**1. attendance**
`sl_no` is Foreign key reference to registration `sl_no` and `AttID` is primary key

[image]

**2. registeration**

 
`sl_no` is primary key

 
[image]

**3. schedule**

 
`id` is primary key

 
[image]

I'm querying my database against `schedule table` and `registration table` to get the schedule start date,end date and students detail `where university is same` as below:

```
<?php   
        $schedule_query = "SELECT a.scheduleStartDate, a.scheduleEndDate, b.sl_no, b.student_name 
        FROM schedule a 
        LEFT JOIN registration b 
        ON a.university = b.university 
        WHERE a.scheduleName = 'XYZ Schedule 01'";

        $result = mysqli_query($link, $schedule_query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $start = strtotime($row['scheduleStartDate']);
        $end = strtotime($row['scheduleEndDate']);
        $date = $start;
        $attendance_array = array();
    ?>
```

I'm displaying the report in table format using following query:

```
    <table width="100%" class="tbl" style="font-size: 12px">
<tr>
<th>Sl No</th>  
<th>Name</th>
<?php
$ttl = '';
while($date <= $end)
{
    $ttl++;
    $student_array = array();
    $stu_name_td = '';
    mysqli_data_seek($result,0);
    //Result came from schedule and registration
    while($innerrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){      
        $atd_query = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE AttDate = '".date('Y-m-d', $date)."' AND sl_no = '".$innerrow['sl_no']."'";
        //results from attendance
        $present_stu_res = mysqli_query($link, $atd_query);
        $attendance_array[$innerrow['student_name']][date('Y-m-d', $date)] =  mysqli_num_rows($present_stu_res) > 0 ? 1 : "A";
    }
    echo "<th>".date('j/m/Y', $date)."</th>";
    $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date);
 }
?>
<th>Num of Days</th>
<th>Attended</th>
<th>Percentage(%)</th>
</tr>
<?php
$count ='';
    foreach($attendance_array as $stu_name=>$innerarray){
$count ++;
?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $count;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $stu_name; ?></td>
    <?php 
        foreach($innerarray as $dateval=>$present_val)
            echo '<td>'.$present_val.'</td>';
           echo '<td>'.$ttl.'</td>';//Total No of Days
            $attended = array_sum($innerarray);
            echo '<td>'.$attended.'</td>';//No of Days Attended
            $percent_cal = $attended / $ttl; 
            $percent = number_format( $percent_cal * 100, 2 ) . '%'; 
            echo '<td>'.$percent.'</td>';//Percentage
    ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php }?>
</tr>
</table>
```

From the above code i'm getting output as below:

```
Student Name 17/06/2015   18/06/2015  19/06/2015 20/06/2015 21/06/2015 Num_of_days Attended Percentage(%) 
Student1       1             A          1           A         1             6           3       60%
Student2       1             A          1           A         1             6           3       60%
Student3       1             A          1           A         1             6           3       60%
```

**My Question is:**
I put attendance for the schedule `XYZ Schedule 01` only for the dates 17th 19th and 21st remaining 2 days i don't want to show in the report and calculate the percentage accordingly how can i achieve? Any help may gretly appriciated.

Comment: Just to tell you, your second foreach is missing a bracket (foreach($innerarray as $dateval=>$present_val))

Comment: are you putting 0 for absent in attendance table?

Comment: @ Vikas Umrao No I'm putting only present status i.e 1

Answer (score 0):

Take out a few lines of code. First line you should take out is

```
<TH>percentage(%)</TH>
```

The next 2 lines you want to delete are

```
$percent = number_format( $percent_cal * 100, 2 ) . '%'; 
echo '<td>'.$percent.'</td>';//Percentage
```